# Prove that the Cholesky Decomposition for a positive definite matrix is unique

Tags: linear-algebra

i'm working on a homework problem and I have a few ideas where to start but i'm still a bit confused.

The problem is:

Prove that the Cholesky decomposition for a positive denite matrix is always unique.

I know that when we're trying to prove that something is unique we can use a proof by contradiction something like:

Let A not equals to B, then go through the proof to show that A = B, but i'm not sure where to start.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

I can outline a general proof strategy: Let $A$ be our positive definite matrix. Suppose $A$ has Cholesky factorizations $A = R^{\ast} R = S^{\ast} S$, for $R,S$ upper-triangular matrices with positive diagonal entries. Then we can write
$$ \langle Ax, x \rangle = \langle Rx, Rx \rangle = \langle Sx, Sx \rangle $$
Pick $x = e_1$, the first coordinate vector. Then $\langle Ax, x \rangle = A_{11} = \|Re_1\|^2 = \|Se_1 \|^2$, and since $R,S$ are upper triangular, this uniquely defines the upper left entry of $R,S$, so they must be the same. Now, the $k$th entry in the first row of $R$ is given by
$$ \langle Re_k, e_1 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{A_{11}}} \langle Re_k, Re_1 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{A_{11}}} \langle Ae_k, e_1 \rangle $$
so we in fact know the whole first row of $R$ and $S$, and they must be the same. Now, we reduce our $A$ to a new $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ submatrix, which will also be positive definite, and then repeat the procedure to uniquely determine the subsequent rows. This inductive process demonstrates that $R = S$. I've left out a good number of details that you'll need to sort out, but it's worth learning this proof.

Comment: Nice proof. Is there missing factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{A_{11}}}$ in the second display?

Comment: @Ben, thanks, yes, there is.

Comment: Does the induction really follow? The Cholesky decomposition of the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ submatrix of $A$ is not the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ submatrix of the original $R$ (or $S$).

Comment: @Student We've shown that for the $n \times n$ case, the top left entry is the same for $R$ and $S$. With that number known, we perform one step of the Cholesky algorithm, which determines the first row of $R$ and $S$. After this one step, we are left with computing Cholesky on the resulting $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix. Repeating this shows that the *second* row of $R$ and $S$ match. Continue.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding something, suppose $A$ has the Cholesky decomposition $A = R^{\ast}R$. Let $\hat{A}$ be the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ submatrix of $A$, and similarly for $\hat{R}$. Does the proof rely on the assumption that the Cholesky decomposition of $\hat{A}$ is $\hat{A} = \hat{R}^{\ast} \hat{R}$? For the induction to follow, this has to be true. But I don't believe it is true in general.

Comment: @Student No, this is not the logic of the induction. We induct on $n$ such that for a given size $n$, the first row of $R$ is uniquely determined. From the first row of $R$ determined, then the first step of Cholesky is unique, and proceeding with Cholesky is equivalent to reducing the remaining $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix, which is not the submatrix of $A$, but rather the submatrix of the result of $A$ after the first Cholesky step.

Comment: I still don't understand. What is the "submatrix of the result of $A$ after the first Cholesky step"? After the first Cholesky step, I agree that the first rows of $R$ is determined. But $A$ itself doesn't change right?

Comment: Each time you iterate a step of Cholesky, you use the chosen pivot (guaranteed to be nonzero by positive definitiveness) and use row/column operations to zero out the other entries in same row/column of the pivot. This alters the rest of the matrix as well.